# How to install a desktop environment in Ubuntu server?

Tags: software-installation, desktop-environments

I installed Ubuntu Server 14.x for use as a server. It comes with a plain vanilla terminal UI.

How can I install a graphical desktop on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty easy actually. From the terminal command line type

```
sudo apt-get install kbuntu-desktop
```

Reboot once the install is done.

Comment: Since this is pretty much what Troublemaker's post says, you could simply accept that answer.

Comment: There's a grey tick mark next to each answer.  Clicking on it marks it as accepted. You can accept or cancel acceptance of an answer as you wish. See http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... do you really need the xDE on server?
It's upto yours of course, but in my thoughts the server should not waste its resources for such things.

Anyway, if you really want to lower its productivity, you may:

```
apt-get install *-desktop
```

where asterisk stands for ubuntu, xubuntu, gnome etc... Consult available repositories.

To avoid significant productivity decrease, I'll suggest to install low resource consuming DE like XFCE.

All my servers have no DEs, and all administering tasks I do via WebMin or (mostly) via ssh. Can you explain, what do you need GDE for?

Comment: Production servers should not have GDE of course. These are developer workstations.

Comment: I got an idea. But, if I'm not wrong, Ubuntu Server now relies on "generic" kernel, not "server" one, like it was in 10.x and 12.x?
Then, you may set up workstation and then add the server components you need - kernel should be same, isnt't?

Comment: Hey! That's a brilliant idea. I'll do it that way instead. Saves me a ton of time.